# Heroku error on scala application

Tags: scala, heroku, scalatra

Any idea what may cause the following error?

```
sinan@ThinkPad-X1-Carbon:~/dev/heroku/kumbaraci50$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 4390, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2419/2419), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4390/4390), 4.11 MiB | 79.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4390 (delta 1552), reused 4338 (delta 1520)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Scala app detected
remote: 
remote: gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote: tar: Child returned status 1
remote: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Scala app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to kumbaraci50-tiyatrosever.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/kumbaraci50-tiyatrosever.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/kumbaraci50-tiyatrosever.git'
```

I was able to push this app couple of days ago with no problem, however something may have changed on my local with package updates.
Is there way to increase verbosity of the logging while deploying the app?

This application uses Scalatra framework 2.3 and scala version 2.11.1 on Java 1.8.0_45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your `LANG` config var is not set to "tr_TR.UTF-8". You can confirm this by running:

```
$ heroku config:unset LANG
```

Certain LANG values result in certificate errors on Heroku. Instead, you may be able to use `-Dfile.encoding` by running this:

```
$ heroku config:set JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=tr_TR.UTF-8"
```

Hope that helps.